# Pathname to a tree structure

Tags: python, tree

I have a list of pathnames:

```
www.example.com/a/b/c/d
www.example.com/a/b/e/f
www.example.com/a/c/d/f
```

and I want to transform it to a dictionary:

```
a : {
  b : {
    c : {
      d : {}
    }
    e : {
      f : {}
    }
  c : {
    d : {
      f : {}
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote very naive code but I wish to automate it, any ideas?

```
keys = paths.replace("www.example.com/", "").split("/")
test = {}

for key in keys:
    for i, k in enumerate(key):
        if i == 0:
            test.setdefault(k, {})
        if i == 1:
            test[key[0]].setdefault(k, {})
        if i == 2:
            test[key[0]][key[1]].setdefault(k, {})
        if i == 3:
            test[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]].setdefault(k, {})
```

Comment: Recursion is your friend.

Comment: You are right thanks. I just don't think recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic recursion:

```
def add_nodes(root, nodes):
    if nodes:
        node = nodes.pop(0)
        root.setdefault(node, {})
        add_nodes(root[node], nodes)
```

Example:

```
>>> addresses = ['www.example.com/a/b/c/d', 'www.example.com/a/b/e/f', 'www.example.com/a/c/d/f']
>>> elts = [addr.split('/')[1:] for addr in addresses]
>>> tree = {}
>>> for elt in elts:
...     add_nodes(tree, elt)
... 
>>> tree
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}, 'e': {'f': {}}}, 'c': {'d': {'f': {}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a solution to help you thinking in recursion, how to merge the result of multiple paths is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
def fun(path):
    if len(path) == 0:
            return
    if len(path) == 1:
            return path[0]
    return {path[0]: fun(path[1:])}

path = "www.example.com/a/b/c/d".split("/")
d = fun(path)
print d
```